# connect circles with border radius and lines

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to connect 3 circle images with dotted border.

My code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="circle"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/fbl21d.png"  /></div>
    <div class="circle"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/fbl21d.png" /></div>
    <div class="circle"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/fbl21d.png" /></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/cfmn0dop/)

I would like to have something like on the image below.

[image: I want to look it like this]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use pseudo selector `:before`, and place border as you want, for example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cfmn0dop/1/)

```
.main:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left: 45px;
    right: 120px;
    top: 70px;
    border-top: 5px dotted #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working. My only problem left is to position it mid...

Comment: @Morpheus: set the next grandparent to `text-align: center;`. Should do the trick in jsfiddle, since there isn't one there (I don't think, anyway), set `html,body{text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pseudo element in conjunction with the `:not` pseudo selector.

This would allow you to add multiple circle classes, and give this effect for more than three elements.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid silver;
}
.circle:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 6px dashed blue;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 3px);
  top: calc(50% - 3px);
  left: -42px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
html,
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @marsh that it could be solved with css pseudo elements but it is better to apply styles to `.circle` class so you cold add as many circles as you want without changing css:

```
.main .circle:not(:last-child):after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

`:not` selector will allow to remove dashed line from `:last-child` of `.main`

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/tqkv8rfz/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution

**[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfmn0dop/7/)**

```
.circle:after {
    content:'-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -';
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: red;

}

.circle.last:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code snippet here, I wouldn't say it was near the most efficient, nor making use of the power of css tbh...